# How to seperate rectangles in tkinter using the canvas function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to figure out how to put my rectangle using the canvas tkinter tool in a certain place. I have read many articles that said it does it for you but every time I change the coordinates, my shape either disappears or is stuck right inside and/or next to another shape.

I want 3 rectangles the same size to appear next to each other with a little gap between each rectangle and I want them to appear vertically. My current code looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('640x480')

c = Canvas(root, height=250, width=300, bg="blue")
c.pack(padx=10, pady=20, side=LEFT)
r = c.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100, fill="yellow", activefill="grey", disabledfill="grey")
f = c.create_rectangle(240,240,100,100, fill="red", activefill="grey", disabledfill="grey")        

r = Canvas(root)
r = c.pack(padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates in create_rectangle are in reference to the canvas. The coordinates are right, top, left, bottom (or x1, y1, x2, y2). So if you want the rectangles to be under each other they have to have the same x values.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('640x480')

c = Canvas(root, height=250, width=300, bg="blue")
c.pack(padx=10, pady=20, side=LEFT)

#                      x1, y1, x2, y2
r = c.create_rectangle( 0,  0, 50, 50, fill="yellow",
                       activefill="grey", disabledfill="grey")
f = c.create_rectangle( 0, 70, 50,120, fill="red",
                       activefill="grey", disabledfill="grey")
p = c.create_rectangle( 0,140, 50,190, fill="green",
                       activefill="grey", disabledfill="grey")

root.mainloop()
```

Note that X1 = 0 for all rectangles, X2 = 50 for all rectangles. That puts them on the same place on the x axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help